# How to filter for multiple criteria in Tableau via Drop Down?

Tags: tableau-api, dropdown

Let's imagine there was the following dataset (arbitrary example):

- Mary, female, plays instrument, lives in New York
- John, male, plays no instrument, lives in Boston
- Dave, male, plays no instrument, lives in Los Angeles

I'd like to create a drop down with the following options:

- Segment A
- Segment B

When selecting segment A, data should be filtered for those who are female and play an instrument (i.e., highlight New York on a map). When selecting segment B, data should be filtered for those who are male and play no instrument (i.e., highlight Boston and Los Angeles on a map).

How could that be implemented with Tableau?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a calculated field, that has a value based on the logic you need, e.g.

IF [Gender] = 'female' AND [Instrument] = 'plays instrument' then 'Segment1' else 'Segment2' END

and then use this field as a filter.

Comment: Thank you, worked when combined with this guide: http://www.vizwiz.com/2012/06/create-global-filter-in-tableau-across.html